# Changing Access modifier to remove duplication code detection in Intelliji

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I made two different java class under same project in intelliJ.Both classes contains exactly same boolean method.Whenever i move cursor over code it shows duplicate code found.Can i make some changes in access modifier to remove this duplication.

I know there is a disabling duplicated code fragment feature in Intellij File settings.

Comment: Do not post questions for your friend, or answer your friends questions. Do not upvote each other. It is voting fraud and can result in a suspension.